# How can dense quark matter stabilize wormholes?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-chromodynamics, wormholes

I have read in several articles, such as
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0577907323000266 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0771 that dense quark matter can stabilize wormholes. Why is it, that it would work, since the weak energy condition is not being violated? How is the NEC violated by dense quark matter in particular?

Comment: As far as I can tell (this is covered in Eric Poisson's YT course, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLaNkJORnlhZkgIyPFNxhJPIVewGckJCGr) this is 100% fantasy fiction.  You apparently need "exotic matter" to reverse the focusing effect of gravitation, but you need "regular" gravitation to enter the wormhole int the first place.  So, not only do we need "exotic matter", we need regular matter on the way in, then it needs to change into the exotic stuff on the way out.  Really?

Comment: Here is a link to Poisson's brief discussion about wormholes: https://youtu.be/vcGDqRm7ZK4?list=PLaNkJORnlhZkgIyPFNxhJPIVewGckJCGr&t=3835

Comment: Thank you, however I still don’t understand how the dense quark matter is supposed to violate NEC. I edited the question in order to clarify

Comment: Can't help with that I'm afraid, don't know anything about particle physics.  Just pointing out a more fundamental conceptual problem.  At least the question is now open again!

Comment: Doing a quick search on Google Scholar, the first article you link to seems to rely on the second one you link to. That second article by Harko et al. has been cited a total of 11 times since its publication in 2015 (one of which that tries applying this idea to the Alcubierre Metric in 2023: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1402-4896/acaf1b ).

Comment: Thank you, however what I still do not understand is how the energy density can be decreased down to a negative value through the large coupling.